# Check if specific array value isset PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a slider for news items and doing a loop to get post info for each. Works fine but I am stuck with one paramater that is returned by json and I loop trough it again . the $xtras parameter returns some additional values one of them is additional intro text. I need to check if this value isset otherwise I need to return default intro text.

problem I have is that if  `$xtra_values->id 44`  does not exists I get the intro text from previous post instead that post `$post['intro']`

$xtras returns stdClass Object like this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [value] => 38
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 28
    [value] => 1
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 44
    [value] => This is extra intro text
)
```

and this is my loop

```
foreach ($post_array as $key=> $posts){

    $xtras  = json_decode($posts['xtra']);

     foreach($xtras as $key=> $xtra_values){

        if($xtra_values->id == 44){
           $intro_text = $xtra_values->value;
        }else{
           $intro_text = $post['intro'];
        }     

     }




      echo $post['title'];.'<br />';
      echo $intro_text;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

foreach ($post_array as $key=> $posts){

```
$xtras  = json_decode($posts['xtra']);
$intro_text = null;


 foreach($xtras as $key=> $xtra_values){

    if($xtra_values->id == 44){
       $intro_text = $xtra_values->value;
    }     

 }
if($intro_text == null){
       $intro_text = $post['intro'];
    }
```

Comment: same as from mgraph ,  does not work and $xtra_values->id  is always set since it returns more than 1 stdClass Object, in both cases now I get only $post[intro]

Comment: is $xtra_values an array of StdClasses?

Comment: foreach($xtras as $key $xtra_values){ to  
 foreach($xtras as $key => $xtra_values){ typo?

Comment: yes just typo , what I need is to check if $xtra_values->id == 44 is set , not if $xtra_values->id is set but dont know how to check for that only

Comment: AWESOME! thank you much ,  I should have gotten myself out that second foreach thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
if(isset($xtra_values->id) && $xtra_values->id >= 0 && $xtra_values->id == 44){
```

Comment: does not work and $xtra_values->id  is always set since it returns more than 1 stdClass Object, in both cases now I get only $post[intro]

Comment: cant do that , look at the json result above ,  I have more than just one

Comment: yes , I know what >= is for ,  but look at the result above , it will check in all cases and always be true